# jQuery UI Draggable: clone item and disable a second drag of the same (original item)

Tags: jquery, user-interface, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following situation:

**The user can select columns from different tables that will be included into a view.**

**I would like to have a separate list for each table's columns and a list with the (user chosen) columns from the view.**

I want the user to drag & drop columns from tables x, y, z into the view.

I have found an interesting

```
 <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/B5PH4/253">JSfiddle</a>
```

This allows me to copy list items from the top div to the target div but it has some issues:

1. The same list item can be copied for infinite times (it should only be included once and then deactivated somehow)
2. There is no way of removing (sending back) the item once put in the target div. **And I mention again that there will be 1 target (the view) and multiple sources (individual tables' columns). I would like the items removed to go back in the right tables.**

I am well aware of the [jQuery UI Sortable with Connect List](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists). But it does not seem to give me the required level of control over the drag-drop sources/targets (issue 2 above),

Have you done something similar? Do you know at least a part of the solution? Or can you recommend me another jQuery plugin that does this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I adapted the lists in the jquery example so it should be what you want.

What happens is the sortable1 & 3 are the tables and sortable 2 is the view.

I Only connected sortable 1 & 3 to 2 but not the other way round to stop dragging back to the table then had a remove button which detaches the item and uses the attribute to put it back in the right place.
you could also keep track of position like this as well

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3{
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li, #sortable3 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
     $( "#sortable1, #sortable3" ).sortable({
        connectWith: "#sortable2"
     });
 $( "#sortable2" ).sortable({});

 $("#sortable1 span, #sortable3 span").click(function(event){
  var item = $(event.target).closest('li');
  $('#'+$(event.target).attr('parent')).append(item.detach());
 });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1<span parent="sortable1" style="color: red">*</span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2<span parent="sortable1" style="color: red">*</span></li>
</ul>
 
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable3" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1<span parent="sortable3" style="color: red">*</span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2<span parent="sortable3" style="color: red">*</span></li>
</ul>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: If I put every ul in a separate div with position:relative, the helper is gone as soon as I drag a li outside it's original list (from #sortable1 to #sortable2 for example). All I have left is the pointer. It still works but it looks awful. Do you have any idea how to fix this? I need the wrappers with position:relative in order to implement Perfect Scroll. If I delete position:relative from the CSS and let everything else intact, the helpers are back.

Comment: Hey @AdrianSuteu I cant seem to replicate this. Here is what ive got [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d0h8d0hk/). Is it possibly a problem with the z-index of your elements?

Comment: Hey @Andrew Mcghie. Thanks a lot again for your interest. Take a look please at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d0h8d0hk/24). I have noticed that **it works if I remove position:relative or overflow:auto/scroll** But I need both of them in order to use perfectscrollbar.

Comment: Cool I figured it out. the helper is a child of the div that it was in which is why it was messing up the scroll bars.
What you need to do is add 
`helper: "clone",
appendTo: document.body`
to sortable 1 and 3 this means that the helper element is cloned and then appended to the body so it is nolonger a child of the div.
you might need to change some of your styles because of this.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answers are very helpful for me!